# Dynamically creating unit labels (K, Mn, Bn, Tn) + adjusting axis limit for dual-axis ggplot2 graph?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a date-time dataset with two columns y1 and y2. y2 is always bigger than y1 by an unknown order of magnitude, and both y2 and y1 can have zeroes. When y2 is really big (in the hundreds of billions), reading it's y-axis is tedious (even with commas)- I want to be able to change 1,000 to K, 1,000,000 to M. 10,000,000 to 10M, and so fourth.

Optional/Bonus- I want change the y-axis for either plots to focus/ show the range of y for which data is available. i.e.- if y2 has values that are all above 1,000,000; don't plot a graph starting from zero for this column. Likewise for y1.

Data:

```
df = data.frame('date' = c(seq(as.Date('2019-01-01'), as.Date('2019-02-01'), 'day')))
df$y1 = runif(nrow(df))
df$y2 = runif(nrow(df)) + 10000000
```

.

My Current Approach:

Calculating how much to scale y2 by:

```
#Calculates nearest power of 10
log10_ceiling <- function(x) {
  10^(ceiling(log10(x)))
}

scale = df$y2 / df$y1
scale = scale[!is.na(scale)]
scale = scale[!is.infinite(scale)]
scale = log10_ceiling(max(scale))/100
```

Plotting:

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = date))
p <- p + geom_line(aes(y = y1, colour = "y1"))
p <- p + geom_line(aes(y = df$y2/scale, colour = "y2"))+ 
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(trans  = ~.*scale, name = "y2"))
p <- p + scale_colour_manual(values = c("blue", "red"))
p <- p + labs(y = "y1",
              x = "date",
              colour = "Parameter")
p <- p + theme(legend.position = c(0.8, 0.9))
p
```

I am aware of `label=unit_format(unit = "B")`, but don't know how to change it dynamically to M, or handle cases where the scale is 10B instead of 1B.

Edit- a problem with how I'm currently calculating the scale is y2 is always plotted to the next order of magnitude. i.e.- if y2 values fall between 10 and 11 for instance, the window shows y2 from 0 to 100.